# Place complex uniqueness constraint in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, constraints

In `Postgres`, I have a table `user_badge` containing three columns, appearing as something like the following.

```
# select * from user_badge;
 id | user_id | badge_id | is_active |
----+---------+----------+------------
 1    bob       00001      False
 2    bob       00002      True
 3    alice     00003      True
 4    alice     00004      False
 5    alice     00005      False
```

In this table, a user can have more than one badge, but each user must not have more than one active badge (i.e. row in which the `is_active` column is True).

Another way of saying this, is that the query

```
SELECT user_id FROM user_badge WHERE is_active;
```

must return unique rows.

This is a constraint I wish to place upon this table. **Is there a way of specifying `Postgres` to guarantee it?** In Postgres's [documentation on constraints](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-constraints.html) I see how can one can place a uniqueness constraint on a column and on a set of columns, but do not see examples where the uniqueness constraint involves a `WHERE`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use a partial or filtered index:

```
create unique index unq_user_badge_user_is_active
    on user_badge(user) where is_active;
```

This is described in the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/indexes-partial.html) in the section on partial indexes.